# How to populate dropdown list with data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, dropdown

I have a stored procedure that pulls data from a database and displays it in a text box; it displays for the textboxes but doesn't display for the dropdown list or textbox that has textmode of date.

I've removed the select value option as it was throwing error SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.\r\nParameter name: value"

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "PP_spSearchReturnCrate";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReceiptNo.Text.Trim()))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@receiptNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceiptNo.Text.Trim();
}
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
sqlConn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sqlDa.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    String DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["returnDte"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    txtReturnDte.Text = DATE;
    txtReceipt.Text = dt.Rows[0]["receiptNo"].ToString(); //Where ColumnName is the Field from the DB that you want to display
    //ddlCustomer0.Text= dt.Rows[0]["custName"].ToString();
    ddlDriver.Text = dt.Rows[0]["driverName"].ToString();
    ddlUnitId.Text = dt.Rows[0]["unitId"].ToString();
    txtNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0]["qtyReturned"].ToString();
    txtLocation.Text = dt.Rows[0]["custLocation"].ToString();
    Panel1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    lblmsg.Text = "No Records Found";
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    btnEdit.Visible = false;
}
```

I want to be able to show the data from the database in a drop down list as well as the date in textbox

Comment: Where's the markup and code for the drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ListItem` first, then add it to the dropdown.

```
ListItem li = new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["custName"].ToString());
ddlCustomer0.Items.Add(li);
```

Comment: But it is not pulling the data from the database

Comment: Put those 2 lines under the line you commented-out.

Comment: I did that and it only works one but once it is refreshed then I get back the same error

Comment: is there another code i should place in the page load as It works once and then receive the same error message when I try to pull information again